# adding instances of dates repeating in column A across 11 tabs (sheets) in a sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates, date

How would I create a formula that shows a sum tally of how many instances each date appears on column A across multiple sheets?
I want to make a formula that will display a total tally of how many orders I had each day. All of my orders are spread out out over multiple sheets. The 1st eleven sheets in my master sales sheet contain the entries for all my sale orders. Every sale is given a new row and on those 11 sheets the date of every order is entered in to Column A of those rows. The same date will appear multiple times since I have multiple sales each day. There are dates entered in other places on those sheets but they aren't referencing dates of sales they are referencing other things that aren't related. I only want to tally up the amount of time each date appears in column A across those 11 sheets and nowhere else. [image]

Answer (score 1):

The solution that follows is based fundamentally on the [COUNTIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480) function to get a conditional count, and [FLATTEN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10307761) to combine the dates from multiple columns into a single column.   [BYROW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930) and [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718) are leveraged to create a single formula that can be applied across an entire range. Those 4 functions are listed immediately below however an effort was made in notes to describe the purpose of all functions used, and to link their names to Google support articles that can provide more detail.

Your question describes 11 columns spread across the same number of sheets.  This solution includes 3 comma-separated ranges (not 11).  It is a simple matter to add the additional ranges to the formulas below using the same syntax.

###### COUNTIF

The [COUNTIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480) function returns a conditional count across a range.
**Syntax:** `=COUNTIF(range, criterion)`

###### FLATTEN

The [FLATTEN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10307761) function combines values from one or more ranges into a single column.
**Syntax:** `=FLATTEN(range1, [range2, …])`

###### BYROW

The [BYROW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930) function groups an array by rows by application of a [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718) function to each row
**Syntax:** `=BYROW(array_or_range, LAMBDA)`

###### LAMBDA

The [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718) function contains a set of names and a formula_expression that uses them. To calculate the formula_expression, you can call the returned function with as many values as the name declares.
**Syntax:** `LAMBDA(name, formula_expression)`

###### NAMED RANGES

I find using [NAMED RANGES](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/63175) instead of `<SheetName>!<cell>:<cell>` addressing makes formulas easier to follow visually and often easier to maintain. You can do the same, using a similar or different naming convention, or replace the [NAMED RANGES](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/63175) with actual range references, as you prefer.  Below are the names used for the 3 date columns used in the formulas.

| Name | Range |
| --- | --- |
| **_s1A** | `Sheet1!A:A` |
| **_s2A** | `Sheet2!A:A` |
| **_s3A** | `Sheet3!A:A` |

## Formula 1

###### Get count beside existing dates

This formula addresses the use case where there is a column of dates in a sheet (like you showed in [your image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SG3Nb.png)) and you want to count how many times each of those dates are repeated in a FLATTENED list of all the date columns throughout the spreadsheet.

- [BYROW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930)  is used to apply the [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718) formula to all rows in A:A
- [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718) function is used to apply the same formulas to each row. the arbitrary variable `r` is used to represent the current row being processed.
- [IF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364) combined with [COUNTA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093991) is used to test for, and skip empty cells
- [IF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364) combined with [DATEVALUE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093039) is used to skip non-dates that may be in the list, and since a [DATEVALUE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093039) will error out on non-dates, it is wrapped in [IFERROR](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304) to return a NULL value (blank) for non-dates
- [COUNTIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480) is now used to count the number of occurrences of `r` in our list of dates

```
=BYROW(A:A, LAMBDA(r, 
   IF(COUNTA(r), 
     IFERROR(
        IF(DATEVALUE(r),
           COUNTIF(FLATTEN(_s1A,_s2A,_s3A),r),
           FALSE)),
     IFERROR(1/0))
))
```

## Formula 2

###### Get the list of dates

If, unlike **Formula 1**, the count will not be hosted beside an existing list of dates, a list of dates must then be generated.  This list is built by flattening all the date columns throughout the spreadsheet, then filtering out any duplicates, as well as non-date values.

- [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718) function is used so that once the list of dates is flattened and sorted, it can be reused based on the arbitrary  variable `d` rather than having to write it out again (in the [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197) function for example)
- [FLATTEN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10307761) function combines all the date columns into a single column and [SORT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150) is used (optional) to return the dates in ascending order
- [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197) is used in combination with [IF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364) and [DATEVALUE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093039) to remove non-dates, and since a [DATEVALUE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093039) will error out on non-dates, it is wrapped in [IFERROR](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304) to return a NULL value (blank) for non-dates
- Wrapping the formula in [UNIQUE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10522653) allows us to remove duplicates as we only want to check the count for each date once

```
=UNIQUE((LAMBDA(d, 
   FILTER(d, IFERROR(IF(DATEVALUE(d),TRUE),FALSE)))
   (SORT(FLATTEN(_s1A,_s2A,_s3A)))
))
```

## Combined Formula

###### Formula 2 as input array for Formula 1

While you can theoretically keep **Formula 1** separate from **Formula 2**, the two formulas can be combined.   `Formula 2`, whose result is an array, becomes a direct replacement for the range `A:A` in **Formula 1**'s [BYROW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930) function.

```
=BYROW(
  ( UNIQUE((LAMBDA(d, 
     FILTER(d, IFERROR(IF(DATEVALUE(d),TRUE),FALSE)))
     (SORT(FLATTEN(_s1A,_s2A,_s3A)))))
   ), LAMBDA(r, 
     { r, COUNTIF(FLATTEN(_s1A, _s2A, _s3A), r) })
)
```

---

## Images

**Formula 1: Get count beside existing dates**
*non-dates (highlighted in red) are ignored: text, numbers, empty cells*
[image]

**Formula 2: Get the list of dates**
[image]

**Combined: Formula 2 as input array for Formula 1**
[image]